# C++ templated function to add int at the end of an array

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make a templated function that has three arguments: an array, the length of the array, and the T value to add to the end of the array. Embarrassingly, I cannot even get the int to work, when eventually I would like to get char to work. Anyways, here is my code:

```
#ifndef INSERTATEND_H
#define INSERTATEND_H
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
T& insertAtEnd(T& a, size_t b, T c)
{
    a[b] = c;
    return a;
}


#endif
//main.cpp file
#include "insertAtEnd.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"HELLO";
    int* b = nullptr;

    b = insertAtEnd(b,0,4);
    std::cout <<"a";
}
```

Comment: What is your reason for doing this? You should be using `std::vector<int>` instead of trying to reimplement a subset of its features.

Comment: `b` is null.  Assigning a value to any memory offset from that pointer is undefined behavior.  You need to allocate memory for it.  If you're trying to dynamically grow the memory, it requires additional management.  You need to learn about pointers and memory management before you start hacking away like this.  It will only result in wasted time and frustration.  Better to sit down and spend an hour reading a good book about it.  On a side note, I find it rather strange that you're writing code that uses templates, yet you don't understand pointers.  Most people learn the latter first.

Comment: Arrays are a very low-level concept. They do not extend their size. You can only create a new one to get a larger one. Also they do not allocate memory or free memory, except when used as local variable. As @user17732522 told, use `vector` instead. `vector` implements `operator[] `, so its elements can be accessed like an array. Its size can be extended with the `push_back` member function.

Comment: I need to use arrays and templates for a lab in school. Anyway you could fix my code or give me some pointers, no pun intended lol

Comment: Are you only allowed to use C arrays or also std::array? Can you use unique_ptr for memory management? Can you preset a maximum array length and just store the current length or would you have to reallocate?